# How to know if element is on top of other element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Let's start for the beginning. I'm making a website that is controlled with body gestural movements (like Kinect). So I'm using an interface between a Daemon running in a PC (server) and a web client developed in JavaScript. So when a Gesture is identified through the server, it send some signal to the client and it reacts accordingly.

The problem is that I know I can't move the mouse pointer programmatically with JavaScript o jQuery, so I made my own pointer with some  element. But then, I have to know when my pointer is on top of others like buttons, links, divs, etc. I can make an algorithm that every time my pointer moves, it checks that the position of the pointer is on top of some element, but I think that it would be extremely inefficient.

My question is if there is any other approach to do this, for example with some event checking or anything like it?

Thank you.

Regards,

Comment: Do you have already an own pointer element and a function to move it over the screen?

Comment: how about this https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.initMouseEvent?

Comment: Yes @Martin Ernst, I have a pointer as a img element and I'm able to move it across the screen. Also, I have a listener for the pointer that triggers everytime its position has changed.

Comment: @code-jaff Is this a solution that works only in Mozilla Firefox? Because I tried the example (of the site) in Google Chrome and nothing happened.

Comment: So your listener has the coordinates of the pointer on the screen you can perform a simple action: `var visitedElem = document.elementFromPoint(coordX, coordY)`. Thats not more work for the browser than following the mousepointer.

Comment: @MartinErnst I think you just saved my life, thank you very much for your answer. I haven't tested it yet, but it should do it. I'll let you know how it worked. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try like this:

```
$(function() {
    if($('#yourTargetId').position().top == 0) {
        alert('div#yourTargetId is on top of #yourContainerId');
    } else {
        alert('div#yourTargetId is NOT on top of #yourContainerId');
    }
});
```

Markup to test:

```
<div id="yourContainerId">
    <div id="yourTargetId" style="position: absolute; top: 10px;">
        Hi, Dave!
    </div>
</div>
```

In this particular example it will output:

`div#yourTargetId is NOT on top of #yourContainerId`

Test it your self on **[this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/LL8bwgj5/)**.

Comment: I know how to check programmatically if my pointer is on top of an object. The problem is that the site will have like a hundred elements, and if I checked everytime that my pointer moves if it is on top of some element, I think is going to be too much work for the browser.